# OleDbDataReader skips first record

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

I have the following code :

```
OleDbDataReader xlsReader =
           new OleDbCommand("Select * from [" +spreadSheetName + "]", xlsFileConnection).
           ExecuteReader();
```

In the `spreadSheetName` parameter i keep my file name.

The connection string for `xlsFileConnection` was set as

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; 
 Data Source='<directory path>';
 Extended Properties='text; HDR=No; FMT=Delimited'"
```

When i start to execute `while (xlsReader.Read())` i take a row #2 but not #1 from data source.

The first suggestion was that `HDR` parameter has invalid value but it seems it's ok.

Comment: Is your file an Excel spreadsheet or a CSV file? Does it actually have a header row? Why are you using Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 rather than Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0?

Answer (score 0):

There are better and easier ways to reading xlsx files, if I were you I would grab closedXML from nuget and this code to read your excel file into a data table

```
public void ProcessExcel(string fileName)
    {
        _dt = ImportSheet(fileName);
        dgContacts.ItemsSource = _dt.DefaultView;
    }

public static DataTable ImportSheet(string fileName)
    {
        var datatable = new DataTable();
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook(fileName);
        var xlWorksheet = workbook.Worksheet(1);
        var range = xlWorksheet.Range(xlWorksheet.FirstCellUsed(), xlWorksheet.LastCellUsed());

        var col = range.ColumnCount();
        var row = range.RowCount();

        datatable.Clear();
        for (var i = 1; i <= col; i++)
        {
            var column = xlWorksheet.Cell(1, i);
            datatable.Columns.Add(column.Value.ToString());
        }

        var firstHeadRow = 0;
        foreach (var item in range.Rows())
        {
            if (firstHeadRow != 0)
            {
                var array = new object[col];
                for (var y = 1; y <= col; y++)
                {
                    array[y - 1] = item.Cell(y).Value;
                }

                datatable.Rows.Add(array);
            }
            firstHeadRow++;
        }
        return datatable;
    }
```

The grab the data out of your datatable as you need.

This is live and working code, so you just need to copy and paste

Comment: The OP asked about OleDb and not ClosedXML so while interesting this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: fully aware of that, but this is a much cleaner execution of getting the data and an alternative method of how to get the data in without having to use the jet engine